# Install Rest Data Services not available in SQL Developer version 22

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-rest-data-services

I am trying to configure ORDS in my SQL Developer (version 22.2).
According to the documentation I should be able to do this from the menu: Tools -> REST Data Services -> Install.

Documentation

[image: 1]

Unfortunately this option is not available for me:

SQLDeveloperScreenshot

[image: 2]

Does anybody know how to properly configure this ?

Thank you.

I've looked through the available documentation and everywhere it's assumed that option should be available.

I've also found an old version of SQL developer 4.13, and there the install option is available. Since this version is not longer supported and is very old I wouldn't want to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So sorry @laura-constantinescu - that Help Topic should not be included in the product anymore.

We removed that feature in early 2022 when we changed the installer for ORDS. It would have required us to update the corresponding Wizard in SQL Developer, and we just weren't seeing many people using this feature.

If you download ORDS 22.4 to you machine and have Java 11 or 17 available, you can follow some prompts from the command-line and have a working, running ORDS in about 5 minutes.

[Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/22.4/ordig/installing-and-configuring-oracle-rest-data-services.html#GUID-8580F2DC-8D8F-47A0-A733-E1BF07CA27A6)

Once downloaded, unzip to a directory, say
C:\oracle\ords

Then open a cmd prompt, cd to C:\oracle\ords\bin

And run this

```
ords --config c:\oracle\ords\config install
```

Answer the questions.

Going forward to start ords, simply

```
ords --config c:\oracle\ords\config serve
```